# Google timeline chart no duration task

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

For Google timeline chart, some tasks have no duration such as start or end indication. I prefer using diamond shape. How to customize Google timeline chart for those special tasks?

Comment: you can manually modify the chart's svg after it has been drawn, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509661/5090771)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works.