# How to customize the horizontal axis of Google Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When I use  format: 'QQQ yyyy' for haxis, there are too many grid lines showing such as

Q1 2000, Q1 2000, Q1 2000, Q2 2000, Q2 2000, Q2 2000, Q3 2000 ...

Each different quarter repeating 3 times, how to control it to only show different quarter once, such as

Q1 2000, Q2 2000, Q3 2000, Q4 2000

Also is it possible to show it in two lines,such as

Q1 
2000

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: to split the labels on two lines, use format --> `'QQQ\nyyyy'` -- as for repeating labels, there are no standard options to control the labels. you could manually modify the chart's svg after it has been drawn, remove the default labels and add your own -- but then they would not match up with the gridlines, so you would have to manipulate those as well -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509661/5090771) of manually adding elements to the chart, includes algorithm for calculating placement...