# Google timeline - how to include a vertical line with current date

Tags: google-visualization

I have a timeline in google created since a spreadsheet but I can´t include a vertical line to show the current date. Appreciate any help.

The code that is generating the timeline is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current');
      var myStoredString = '{"containerId": "example3.1",' +
        '"dataSourceUrl": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13O7jpSMh1c9GcvP4FeFQr3ehiVYhRRoVGwkSN2SyoAY/edit#gid=0",' +
          '"query":"SELECT A,B,D,E",' +
        '"chartType": "Timeline",' +
        '"options": {' +
        '   "alternatingRowStyle": true,' +
        '   "colorByRowLabel": true,' +
        '}' +
      '}';
      function drawVisualization() {
        google.visualization.drawChart(myStoredString);
      }
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
    </script>
    <div id="example3.1" style="height: 240px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical reference line in google timeline visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872915/vertical-reference-line-in-google-timeline-visualization) -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509661/5090771)...