# How can I get text below each event in event timeline chart in Google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

Is there any way to get data/text below each event of event timeline chart in google charts? 
I am not getting any example depicting the same. It would be very helpful if any one help me out with this.[image]

As can be seen I have highlighted the part which I am trying to do using google charts. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: there are no options provided by the chart for this, you can add manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509661/5090771) _might_ help -- but the chart will not leave room on the same row to add anything...